# Detect HWND Visibility Change

Tags: c#, .net, windows

Is there a way to register a handler to be notified when my application's windows change visibility based on the OS (or anyone else) accessing the HWND directly via something like ShowWindow() with SW_HIDE, etc.?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: Ah sorry about that. Will do..

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your application is WinForms based. Yes, that should be possible by overriding the `WndProc` of your main `Form`.
See `WndProc` [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc.aspx) for details.

Comment: In particular, you need to look for the [WM_SHOWWINDOW message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).